# Login failed for user 'root'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

im trying to create a forgot password page. where user will put their email address on the box provided. when the email is submitted it will be filtered whether it is on the database or not. im having error on con.Open(); where the error "Login failed for user root" always happen when i try to press submit button. thanks for the help in advance

```
    string username = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM user_tbl WHERE email = @Email"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txbx_email.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        username = sdr["Username"].ToString();
                        password = sdr["Password"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txbx_email.Text.Trim());
            mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
            mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Your password is {1}.<br /><br />Thank You.", username, password);
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "***@gmail.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "***";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            lbl_message.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lbl_message.Text = "Password has been sent to your email address.";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_message.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lbl_message.Text = "This email address does not match our records.";
        }
```

Comment: is database connection string right?

Comment: why are you storing plaintext passwords? and why are you sending the password in an email!  Don't do that!

Comment: @MahediSabuj yes, i double checked it, still having error on con.Open();

Comment: @MitchWheat just a prototype sir. just trying stuff with my project.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you are trying to connect to the database using via user `root` which is not added as a logins to your server.

Either change the user that is allowed to login to your server or give `root` user login permission to your sql server

User can be added to the server allowed logins through this option

> Server > Security > Logins

Comment: here is my connection <add name="DBcon" connectionString="data source=localhost; Database=sad; user=root; password=''" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>

Comment: You cannot connect to `mysql` using `SqlConnection`